# sort lines of a file based on a column which has text and numbers

Tags: sorting, awk, sed

I have a file with huge number of lines. these lines are appended with text at the end. now i want these lines to be sorted in increasing order.

Example:

```
I have {few_1} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_101} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_21} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_11} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_31} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_41} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_51} lines here like this and so on
```

I need the file to look like this:

```
I have {few_1} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_11} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_21} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_31} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_41} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_51} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_101} lines here like this and so on
```

I have tried this, but this is not working as expected.

```
sort -k7,7 -n filename
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: note that for code or data, select the block you want formatted, then use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box. Good luck.

Comment: Why did you change your data? Do you still need help?

Comment: yes please.. i tried -k3.2n.. with htis kind of data

Comment: use `sort -k3.7n` . Again, I expected `-k3.6n` to work, but when that didn't work I incremented the number. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell `sort` to skip over chars in a field using a `.n` notation following the key number.

I expected that `-k7.5n` would be the correct key as the numbers seem to start in the 5th position. May sort is counting the space that is the default field delimiter as well.

This also assumes that your data is as regular as your sample and that field 7 always has a word that is 4 chars long before the # part. If that changes, then you'll have to preprocess your file. That would be a separate Q here on S.O.

```
sort -k7.6n file
```

**output**

```
I have few lines here like this1 and so on
I have few lines here like this11 and so on
I have few lines here like this21 and so on
I have few lines here like this31 and so on
I have few lines here like this41 and so on
I have few lines here like this51 and so on
I have few lines here like this101 and so on
```

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
sort -nk2 -t_ file
```

This splits the line at the underscore, and makes a numerical sort of the second column.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please upvote and/or accept answers posts that answer your question.

Comment: @rajaswisaka are you guaranteed to never have a `_` in the text before the `{few_1}` part? If so this will work, if not edit your sample input/output to include that case.

Answer (score 1):

To do this robustly regardless of what other text appears on each line:

1) Prepend with the number from the string `{<non-close-brace>_<number>}` you want to isolate to use for sorting:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*\{[^}]+_([0-9]+)\}.*/\1\t&/' file
1       I have {few_1} lines here like this and so on
101     I have {few_101} lines here like this and so on
21      I have {few_21} lines here like this and so on
11      I have {few_11} lines here like this and so on
31      I have {few_31} lines here like this and so on
41      I have {few_41} lines here like this and so on
51      I have {few_51} lines here like this and so on
```

2) sort:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*\{[^}]+_([0-9]+)\}.*/\1\t&/' file | sort -n
1       I have {few_1} lines here like this and so on
11      I have {few_11} lines here like this and so on
21      I have {few_21} lines here like this and so on
31      I have {few_31} lines here like this and so on
41      I have {few_41} lines here like this and so on
51      I have {few_51} lines here like this and so on
101     I have {few_101} lines here like this and so on
```

3) Remove the number you prepended in step 1:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*\{[^}]+_([0-9]+)\}.*/\1\t&/' file | sort -n | cut -f2-
I have {few_1} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_11} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_21} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_31} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_41} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_51} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_101} lines here like this and so on
```

This is a very common approach to solving various sorting problems.

Answer (score 1):

Why this didn't work for you? For the sort subfield indexing you need to set the `-b` option to ignore the leading space.  this will sort from that key onward, probably what you wanted.

```
$ sort -k3.6bn file

I have {few_1} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_11} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_21} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_31} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_41} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_51} lines here like this and so on
I have {few_101} lines here like this and so on
```